# Autocorrect columns 'states' rom a column using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an CSV file containing a column "State" which contains Indian State names like: "Uttarakh8nd", "Chhat1sgarh", "Assan" etc. I want to modify this column so that they contain correct names as: "Uttarakhand", "Chhattisgarh", "Assam"  instead of the text containing numbers and wrong spelling.

**Sample Table Input :**

```
  State

Uttarakh8nd
Chhat1sgarh
Assan
```

**Expected Output:**

```
State
Uttarakhand
Chhattisgarh
Assam
```

What i have tried so far:

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

spell  = SpellChecker()
def spell_check(x):
    correct_word = []
    mispelled_word = x.split()
    for word in mispelled_word:
        correct_word.append(spell.correction(word))
    return ' '.join(correct_word)

df['State'] = df['State'].apply(lambda x: spell_check(x))
print(df['State']
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help

Comment: You are applying the spell_check function at the axis=0 level. So each word goes into the spell_check() function separately. Then the word is split in letters, so I don't think this works at all.
Are you sure the SpellChecker is also able to correct the Indian states?

Comment: I have tried using autocorrect library as well but couldn't get over this, gives the letter as it is without any correction when there is any integer into it.

Comment: does it work with df['State'].apply(spell_check(axis=1)) ? From the documentation (pandas.DataFrame.apply): Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame. Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the DataFrame’s columns (axis=1)

Comment: @xkudsraw  - No Its not working

Comment: You didn't do something wrong. The problem is that the `spellchecker` didn't find the correct word, try `print(spell.correction('Uttarakh8nd'))` to demonstrate this.